# how to pass complex object to Web API method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, c#-5.0

i have two models :-

```
public class Builder    
{  
    [Key]  
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
    public int BuilderId { get; set; }  
    public string BuilderName { get; set; }  
}
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BuilderId { get; set; }

    public Builder builder { get; set; }
}
```

When i am trying to post the builder class object from client side to the web api method, then it is reading the object from body. there is no problem in that. but when i am trying to add any Project with some Builder then it is not calling to desired method. and my Web Method :-

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProject([FromUri] Project project)
       {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, project);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = project.ProjectId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

my method to call the web api method :-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Project projects)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String contentStr = serializer.Serialize(projects);

            ObjectContent content = new ObjectContent(typeof(Project), projects, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            HttpResponseMessage putResponse = await client.PostAsync(serviceprovider + "project/postproject", content);

            putResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

As per my knowledge, i think it is creating problem because my object is complex. I am new to Web API any suggestions from you are welcome. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has a nested class type object property and you tried to pass it in a URI. I had the similar problem and one of my worked models was exactly the same structure as yours. No solution was available unless passing it with serialized JSON or XML in the request body. Thus I created a custom model binder, the FieldValueModelBinder class. It works excellent and easy in the model you presented, i.e., an object hierarchy without any collection. Since the data volume is not large, it’s pretty good to pass the data in a URI.

Please read my article and download source code I have just posted using this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects. I hope that this is the ideal solution you need.